# playwright firefox.launchPersistentContext timeout

Tags: node.js, firefox, playwright

I want to open a context using playwright firefox based on an session dir, on my pc, it work perfectly, but on 3 diffrent remote desktop connection pc (vps windows server) there are an error. The browser is open after 30s it say the error :

```
browserType.launchPersistentContext: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
<launching> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\firefox-1322\firefox\firefox.exe -no-remote -wait-for-browser -foreground -profile ./browser_data/thread-test -juggler-pipe about:blank
<launched> pid=924
[pid=924][out]
[pid=924][out] Juggler listening to the pipe
[pid=924][err] IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
[pid=924][err] IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
[pid=924][err] IPDL protocol Error: Received an invalid file descriptor
============================================================
    at async C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\gen\index.js:128:23 {
  name: 'TimeoutError'
}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbHT.png)

The code that I use :

```
const {firefox} = require('playwright')
const context = await firefox.launchPersistentContext('./browser_data/thread-test', {headless:false,});
```

I think there is an error on connect browser to playwright step but I don't know how to fix...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Probably this is the same issue like in https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/12632. There is a workaround in the comments for it until its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { rm } from 'fs';
import { firefox } from 'playwright';


rm('/context/sessionstore-backups', () => {});
rm('/context/sessionCheckpoints.json', () => {});
rm('/context/sessionstore.jsonlz4', () => {});

context = await firefox.launchPersistentContext(
  '/context',
  { headless: false }
);
page = context.pages()[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Acctually, we need to remove `sessionstore-backups` and `sessionstore.jsonlz4` in the `userDataDir` folder